# Запуск shell скрипта в node.js

Tags: linux, node.js, shell

Как из node.js запустить на исполнение кокой либо shell скрипт? Такое возможно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Там пример выполнение 'ls', так же можно запустить любой shell скрипт